# Convergence of Two interrelated Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Consider two sequences described below:
$$\alpha_{t+1} = (1-\beta_t^2)\alpha_t,$$
$$\beta_{t+1} = (1-C \alpha_t\alpha_{t+1})\beta_t,$$
where $C>0$ and we know $0 <\beta_1<1$ and $0<\alpha_1<1$.  Determine $\alpha_t$ and $\beta_t$ as a function of $C$ and $\beta_1$ and $\alpha_1$ for all $t \geq 2$ (if doing so is possible).

The answer to the following simpler task is sufficient in my case: what value $\alpha$ and $\beta$ converge to and with what rate?

Intuitively, I think $\alpha$ should converge (nearly) linearly to $0$ but $\beta$ should converge sublinearly to a nonzero quantity. On the other hand, this is also reminiscent of the fixed-point iteration which may help with showing the convergence.

Comment: I have a question pertaining to the sentence "Determine ... for all $t\geq 2$". I want to know whether this can even be found out. Therefore, I would like to know the source of this problem. The idea is that if it's from a textbook or from a PDF or exam, then at least I can believe that there is a closed form. If it's a research problem or an open problem from a paper, I might be more concerned and try and just find the limits and convergence rates.

Comment: Also, I request you to edit the response to my comment into your question. Thanks.

Comment: It is something that I am facing to prove a theoretical convergence result for a research project. Therefore, the exact characterization is not of particular importance, the rate of convergence and the limit points are of interest.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Actually I obtained a second order recursion for $\alpha_i$ (not involving the $\beta_i$) but it's terrifying to deconvolute.

Comment: So I made some plots using Python, and while it seems to be the case that $\alpha_i$ is strictly positive for all $i>0$, the limit of the $\alpha_i$ is *not always* $0$, but instead it seems to be zero for a small positive values of $\alpha_2$ and becomes positive at some threshold value.